# jquery + ajax replace class

Tags: jquery, ajax

I trying to replace button class with ajax, what i do wrong?

my button:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm addLike" name="{{ answer.pk }}" value="Like" ></input>
```

my js:

```
$('.addLike').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{% url 'add_like' %}",
        data: {'answer_pk': $(this).attr('name'), 
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            alert(response.message);
            if ( $(this).hasClass('btn-default')) {
                $(this).removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-success');
            }
            else if ($(this).hasClass('btn-success')) {
                $(this).removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-default');
                }

            }
    }); 
})
```

message, it's just test alert message from my django view function. Problem only with replace element

Comment: Inside the callback, `$(this)` refers to the jqXHR object of the Ajax call, not the element the event handler was bound to.

Comment: you can create a variable before your ajax call and set the current object in that variable and use it in the success callback.

Comment: thank's I will try this

Comment: let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the callback, `$(this)` refers to the `jqXHR` object of the Ajax call, not the element the event handler was bound to.

Try doing this:

```
$('.addLike').click(function() {

    var element = this; // adding the current object in a variable

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{% url 'add_like' %}",
        data: {
            'answer_pk': $(element).attr('name'),
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response.message);
            if ($(element).hasClass('btn-default')) {
                $(element).removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-success');
            } else if ($(element).hasClass('btn-success')) {
                $(element).removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-default');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @DinoMyte thanks but your answer was right too but not in this context. he wanted to get the object in the callback event and my answer was doing that. other than that your answer is perfectly right.

Comment: sorry for nooby question, if I want to save this class after reload page, i must do this on server site of django or I can do it by ajax way?

Comment: you can save it in a cookie if you dont want to do it server side or you can store it in the local storage

Comment: Thank you. I mean, I cant do this by this script? So i just add condition in my Django template

Comment: where do you want to save the class? do you want it to be stored on the client side or the server side? for server side you can use this ajax call and pass the className to server and store it or simply store it in the cookie or localStorage using javascript

Comment: I store it in server side,  thank you a lot, I will try to find this solution by ajax

Comment: just pass it as an extra parameter in your url and you will get it in the server side

Answer (score 1):

A simple toggleClass would do the job, without checking for individual classes and adding and removing them.

```
$("input").click(function()
{
    $(this).toggleClass('btn-default btn-success');
    alert($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vwLfxdya/